# Input validator keeps stopping to ask for more input

Tags: c, validation, user-input

I'm making a function to validate an integer within a domain and ask the user to type again if the number is out of range or if they typed in a character(or string of characters) or if they typed in more than just an integer. The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//\input stream clear function\*
void clear()
{
    char c;
    while((c=getchar())!='\n'&&(c=getchar())!=EOF){}
}

//getchar(char str[], min, max)
int GetInt(char msg[], int min, int max)
{
    int value;
    int rc;
    char ovflow;
    while (true) 
    {
        printf("%s", msg);
        rc = scanf("%d%c",&value,&ovflow);
        if(rc == 0 || rc == 1)
        {
            printf("**No input accepted!**\n\n");
            clear();
        }
        else if(ovflow != '\n')
        {
            printf("**Trailing characters!**\n\n");
            clear();
        }
        else if(value < min || value > max)
        {
            printf("**Out of range!**\n\n");
        }
        else break;
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    int value=GetInt("enter value: ",2,20);
    return 0;
}
```

Things work fine but when I typed in "something", the program froze until I press another Enter. It should look like this:

[It froze if I typed in some certain string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtUQS.png)

It should still print the `printf("%s", msg);` and immediately prompt for more input. I could guess it was because of `clear()` function but whatever I tried, I could not fix it. I would be thankful if you can help me with this.

Comment: `while((c=getchar())!='\n'&&(c=getchar())!=EOF){}` Just call `getchar` once. Ex: `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}`

Comment: Thank you for that, it works flawlessly

Comment: ...and `int c` too. The `getchar()` returns `int` not `char` despite its name, which is short for 'getcharacter'. Besides needing the extra range to hold `EOF` distinct from `0xFF`, a character such as `'a'` has type `int` too.

Comment: Don't try to do input validation with `scanf`, it's going to end in tears. Use `fgets`, read an entire line and parse that possibly with `sscanf` or `strtol` or `strtod` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Right, Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to just call `getchar()` once. ex:

```
((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
```

From [a comment by Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127037/input-validator-keeps-stopping-to-ask-for-more-input/71127410#comment125731195_71127037)

Comment: The 'at' symbol only works in a comment (one attribution per comment).

Comment: But you can link to a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127037/input-validator-keeps-stopping-to-ask-for-more-input#comment125731195_71127037). The link can be copied by a right-click on the time-stamp at the end of the comment.